# Laravel Routing and Angular JS with UI router

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-4

I am building a simple Data Logging WEB APP using Laravel and Angular JS but I am having a problem with my routing.

Here is my current Route

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth','prefix'=>'dashboard'), function(){
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'dashboard.index','uses'=>'DashboardController@index'));
   Route::get('/devices/{id}', array('as'=>'devices','uses'=>'DashboardController@devices'));
});
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'api'),function()
{
   Route::resource('users', 'UsersController',array('except'=>array('edit','create')));
   Route::resource('devices', 'DevicesController',array('except'=>array('edit','create')));
}
```

Everything is OK when I am at the index page but using the same templates, when I navigate to /device/{id}, I get this error message

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://arduino.dev/dashboard/devices/app/views/dashboard/index.html

It is concatenating dashboard/devices to the ui-router

Here is my app.config

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider

    .state('devices',{
        url:'/',
        resolve:{
            devices:function(Device){
                return Device.query().$promise;
            }
        },
        templateUrl:'app/views/dashboard/index.html',
        controller:"DeviceController"
    })
    .state('devices.create',{
        url:'/create',
        templateUrl:'app/views/dashboard/device_create.html',
        controller:"DeviceController"
    })
```

I want to separate the  device/{id} in another view to make another SPA for easier maintenance.
I tried /foo, /bar but the same error occurs.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: your laravel do not serve static files outside public folder, at least default setup don't do. by the looks of the path `app/views/dashboard/index.html` it will be a view, but you name it as html. If it is a view, then where is your route/controler to handle the view. If it is static html, move it to public folder.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, this html files are located in the public folder.